# Shifted position of Task Manager even after changing it

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, aero-snap

The task manager shifts from its position even if I change its position to some other place.
[image]

Note the gap of few pixels.

After shifting it so that it reaches the edge of the screen.
[image]

Now it is at the edge of the screen.

If I close task manager and open it again, it returns to its original position before changing.
[image]

Note the gap again.

But if I move it at a place like this and open it again after closing it, it opens at the same place.

[image]

Like this.

So, my question is, is it possible to make it reach the edge of screen.Kind of a perfectionist problem.

Edit: Tried upvoted comment by John, didn't help.

Edit: Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+ right arrow also eliminates the gap but it still returns to the position after reopening.

Edit: If I increase the size of the task manager window, I noticed that the arrow to adjust the size doesn't go past the blank space and doesn't allow me to increase the size.

Comment: If you have Task Manager open in a regular Window and then move it to an edge or corner manually, it will remember that position.

Comment: @John Yes I moved it manually to the edge by mouse but it still goes back to that position.

Comment: Something wrong. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run first: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restore-health  followed second by SFC /SCANNOW  .  Allow all to complete, close out all apps including Task Manager, restart and test.

Comment: @John Any idea how this would help with this strange behavior?

Comment: No. I have used Task Manager for years and it goes where I put it.

Comment: @John Will try it out and update the question.

Comment: @John It didn't help.

Comment: At this point, you may need to rebuild Windows. I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: @John Seems like it is not worth the pains of rebuilding windows and stuff.

Comment: Yes I understand. At some point, all machines need rebuilding and so leave it until that day arrives.

Comment: @John Mind giving me an example of when?

Comment: New Feature upgrades may be an opportunity.  Mid-May V2004 may be out and then take a weekend to backup and install the Feature upgrade fresh. I did run out of ideas on this one.

Comment: @John Yup, that seems to be a great opportunity.

Comment: Thunderbird has THE SAME behaviour. So it's not an issue only of Task Manager. File Explorer shows the same issue. So does Edge. Chrome doesn't. Firefox doesn't. Looks like some parameter the developers can set or not.

Comment: @1NN Just a small thing to note, I am not using any external display port connection, it is just the my laptop screen with this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Unfortunately this seems a "feature" baked into the Windows 10 UI.
As a partial workaround you can:
a) press `Win`+`arrow` to place Task manager at the (left or right) edge, then use the mouse to reduce the size from half-screen to what you need
b) during your work session, instead of closing task manager, minimize it. It will resume the position when you bring it back up.
c) unfortunately you'll have to repeat step a) every time you've logged out (or closed TM).
d) if you don't want to completely resize your task manager to "less than half screen size" every time, you might want to try [PowerToys / FancyZones on github](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/tree/master/src/modules/fancyzones), which lets you customize the aero-snap window sizes in many ways. I haven't tried this out, though.

### Some explanations

There's an [old thread in the Display Fusion developer's forum](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/windows-10-windows-snapping-a-few-pixels-off/?ID=8dae7bc8-1e10-44dc-9e39-fb3887f18aae)  which shows that the issue / or feature (?) exists since at least 2015.
It looks like it's a standard behaviour in Windows 10: if the developer wants to offer something else, it needs to be coded into the software:
if you look at the behaviour of a software like firefox, for example, you'll see that once you open it, it will first take a position just as task manager does: a few pixels from the edge of the screen. Then, some miliseconds later, the window will resize to occupy the position in which it was closed, going to the edge of the screen.

This is why my guess is: if the SW developer has not thought of it, you as user can't do anything. Only very few elements of the Win 10 UI  are available through the registry, even less through the user interface.
Even the "themes" that are available through the Microsoft store really just a bunch of photos and maybe an 'accent color': a long long long way away from changing any design feature. 
So: with Win 10, Microsoft has a strong grip on the 'design' they choose.

One more aspect: If a window is closed when it is positioned half way off-screen, or in-between 2 monitors, upon reopen it will be forced back onto the screen, a few pixels away from the edge just as Task Manager. So, at its basis it seems to be a 'user-friendly' behaviour. Also, the basic design decision seems to be: "only maximised windows should touch the left or right screen edge". This can make sense in many situations, as in general it can give more clarity to the UI,  but in your situation for sure it's a pain which simply the MS deveolpers didn't think of.

Comment: The PowerToys worked for me. Wish Microsoft takes this problem into consideration tho.